# HostBasedRegexpVirtualURIMapping configuration in Magnolia 5.4.1 CE not working

Tags: regex, servlet-filters, magnolia

I think I found a bug with Magnolia's [HostBasedRegexpVirtualURIMapping](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/service/local/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/archive/info/magnolia/magnolia-core/5.4.1/magnolia-core-5.4.1-javadoc.jar/!/info/magnolia/cms/beans/config/HostBasedRegexpVirtualURIMapping.html). I am using Magnolia 5.4.1 CE.

I have the following pages:

[image]

and the following mapping configured:

[image]

My intention is that a request to:

http://www.area1.local:8888/magnoliaAuthor/subarea/home

gets forwarded to the page: /**area1**/subarea/home

while a request to:

http://www.area2.local:8888/magnoliaAuthor/subarea/home

gets forwarded to the page: /**area2**/subarea/home

**However, it does not work, the forwarding does not take place.**

---

Interestingly, the following cases work though:

**Alternative 1:**

I change the `fromURI` to `/subarea/(.*).html` like this:
[image]

and then, a reques to 
http://www.area1.local:8888/magnoliaAuthor/subarea/home.html

gets forwarded to the page: /**area1**/subarea/home

However, I do not want to use the ".html" in the url.

---

**Alternative 2:**

Second option that works as well is using the [HostBasedVirtualURIMapping](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/service/local/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/archive/info/magnolia/magnolia-core/5.4.1/magnolia-core-5.4.1-javadoc.jar/!/info/magnolia/cms/beans/config/HostBasedVirtualURIMapping.html) instead of the `HostBasedRegexpVirtualURIMapping`, but of course, this approach is a bit tiring to configure for each url.

[image]

This make my URI mapping work as intended, but I do not want to configure every possible fromURI but would rather like to use regular expressions.

---

So my question is, what is wrong with the original configuration of my `HostBasedRegexpVirtualURIMapping`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong? This use case is simply not supported in community edition. If you want to map multiple sites & multiple hosts from one Magnolia instance you need to use enterprise edition not community.

Comment: Update: I did some debugging and in fact, the regular expression does not work this way with the standard HostBasedVirtualURIMapping class. With a custom/extended URI mapper class and just an additional LinkTransformer, it's working fine though, even on CE. Of course, it's not fully-fledged multi-site support as in EE, but covers the basic requirements mentioned above.